# changing the url site for css to consistent one

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a css for my site on wordpress

```
body {
background: #e5ddc8 url(http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fredshotel-headbgg.png) top left repeat-x;
}
```

I want to change the url to a more consistent code by using function because if ever I change my site location it will not detect the url since i change the url. what is the right call to output the site url of my site.

```
body {
background: #e5ddc8 url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fredshotel-headbgg.png) top left repeat-x;
}
```

I try to use this code but nothing happens the image doesn't load. I also tried the get template directory and get_url but the php doesn't seem to work inside my css.

Comment: If you change background of the site, go to Apperance->background

Comment: I have to use the css not the background from wordpress settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placed the image on my themes folder under images using the FTP

then change my css to this

```
body
{
    background: #e5ddc8 url(images/fredshotel-headbgg.png) top left repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because beginning a url with / means from the root of the website, and your website appears to be inside a subdirectory.  In example two, your site is looking for this file at http://fabioide.com/wp-content...... etc.  instead of http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/wp-content.

The easy fix would be to not begin the css background url line with a /.  So instead of:

background: #e5ddc8 url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fredshotel-headbgg.png) top left repeat-x;
}

it should be:
background: #e5ddc8 url(wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fredshotel-headbgg.png) top left repeat-x;
}

That should do it, depending on the url rewriting going on.  For instance, if you're on page: 
http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/category/page it would look for the file in http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/category/page/wp-content, etc.  So if you could let me know if your css is a php file, you could capture the siteurl from the database and then echo that there like this:

```
background: url('<?php get_site_url(); ?>'/wp-content/etc...);
```

You'd have to connect the css file to the wordpress core I think though to get access to that function.

Comment: I already fixed my problem by placing my image using the FTP and placing it on the themes image folder then changing the code to this 

`body
{
    background: #e5ddc8 url(images/fredshotel-headbgg.png) top left repeat-x;
}`

the `url(wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fredshotel-headbgg.png)` doesnt work too. my css file is a .css not php

Comment: And PHP CAN be used in a css file.  replace the file extension of the css file to .php and change the references to it.  For future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using relative url in your css - ( relative to where the css ) .

for example

if you had your image and css folder in same directory, then

url('../images/my/path/to/image.jpg');

** Also - php won't work in your .css - howver you could use .htaccess to parse the file as php if you needed to .

Comment: Yep. i did this by placing the image where the css is located but on a folder "images" then using this url(images/fredshotel-headbgg.png)

Answer (score 0):

That path would be relative to Css folder , do it would be looking in css/images - you need to do ../images - that would move up one level